# Flutter: How can I prevent button from overflowing the parent container?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, button, widget

I am trying to create a widget that has a button at the very bottom. What it should look like

[image]

However, the bottom of my button is extending beyond the parent container and I'm not sure how to fix that.

What my code currently produces

[image]

This is the code I currently have. I have tried using Sizedbox, and hard coding the size, but it still overflows the parent container.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 210,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        color: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/images/clock.png',
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            "You have no upcoming appointments",
            style: TextStyle(color: catCharlie),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(cocoGypsy),
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(LinearBorder.none),
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Schedule an appointment',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13, color: bishop),
                ),
                const Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                  size: 16,
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Spacer` widget to force the button push to the bottom. And use `clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias` or `hardEdge` on top container, default it is `Clip.None`.

```dart
Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  height: 210,
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    color: Colors.blueGrey,
  ),
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
        // child: Image.asset(
        //   'assets/images/clock.png',
        // ),
      ),
      Text(
        "You have no upcoming appointments",
        // style: TextStyle(color: catCharlie),
      ),
      // const SizedBox(
      //   height: 30,
      // ),
      Spacer(),
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(cocoGypsy),
          fixedSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(const Size.fromHeight(50)),
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Schedule an appointment',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13, color: bishop),
            ),
            const Icon(
              Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
              size: 16,
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```